# Get number of commits since a tag from another branch with a git command

Tags: git

I'm trying to find the number of commits since a tag, in another branch than main (main beeing the branch where the tags are created).
I've checked several q/a around here suggesting 'git rev-list' and 'git describe' (with lots of combinations of flags and different order of parameters) without much success, in my case to get the right number...

For our example, we have 2 branches being `main` and `dev`.

In our workflow we tag main with the new version on release. We then merge `main` to `dev`.
Starting from there I would love to get the number of commits in `dev`, since this version/tag **only**.

Let's say we've just tagged `main` with 'v1.2.3' and merged `main` into `dev`.
If I change a file in `main` and commit it, the following command will yield '1' and that's perfect.

```
`git rev-list v1.2.3..HEAD --count`
```

Now if I checkout `dev` and use the same command in this context, I'm getting something like 17. **I want to obtain 0 in this case**  (or 1 for the merge entry).
If I then edit/commit a file here in `dev` and run this command I've got 18; the +1 is expected.

How to "reset" this counter to 0 when I merge `main` into `dev` and start counting from then? Or what's the good parameters to use?
Again I tried with the parameters `--first-parent` / `--no-merges` and so on; I can reduce the number but never get 0 or 1 (1 might be for the commit of the merge, and I'll be fine with that as well)

Thanks

Comment: When you merge `main` into `dev`, you have at least one commit, the merge commit. How can you expect to be able to reset some commit counter to 0, when you are guaranteed to have at least 1?

Comment: I try to specify "or 1" for this case, but in my case with a recently created test repository I get 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those 17 commits are most likely *siblings* to the `v1.2.3` commit, accumulated in `dev` since `main` was frozen for release testing.  They neither precede nor follow `v1.2.3` in the history.  In this case, it looks like `git` is telling you about all the commits since the common ancestor of the two branches.

If you count from the merge commit instead of the tag, you'll get the zero you're looking for, but that discounts those 17 commits to dev and makes it appear that your current state in `dev` is `v1.2.3` when it's really `v1.2.3` + 17 other commits.

Sample repo:

```
* eb8a717 | HEAD -> dev | first commit to dev after main merged back in
*   2862ad6 |  | Merge branch 'main' into dev
|\  
| * 33cf7dd | tag: v1.2.3, main| patch to initial version
* | 9458df5 |  | second commit to dev since branching
* | 53d6d29 |  | first commit to dev since branching
|/  
* 2ffc809 |  | first commit
```

```sh
$ git rev-list --count v1.2.3...HEAD
4

$ git rev-list --count 2862ad6...HEAD
1
```

Perhaps you want to tag the merge commit as `v1.2.4` or `v1.3.0` or `v2.0.0` as appropriate, and count from that tag instead?

Comment: Perfect, using the merge-commit hash instead of the tag is what's needed! Also yes, maybe I'll add a tag (1.2.3-dev-0 in my case) for the merge-commit, it'll be easier to find. Thanks a lot!